# Postfix decrement

Tags: c

I have a very simple question.

in this piece of code when will the value of n be decremented?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void func(int n)
{ 
  //text//
}

int main()
{
  int n=10;
  func(n--);
  return 0;
}
```

now when func() is called is the value of n decremented when control comes back to main() or is it decremented at that time only but n=10 is passed to func().
Please explain, also if there is a way to check the value then that will be really helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a function is called, all it's arguments are evaluated (in an implementation-defined order) **before the function can start** - it's a sequence point. So, **after** all the arguments are evaluated the function can finally begin.

What this means is that `n--` is evaluated and yields the value `10` for the function. At the moment the function has begun `n` is already 9 but the `n` parameter of the function hold the value `10`.

A simple way to check this:

```
void func(int n, int *np)
{
    printf("Outside: %d\n", *np);
}

int main(void)
{
    /* ... */
    func(n--, &n);
}
```

Comment: BUt when we use ++n then incremented value is passed why?

Comment: @Mr.32 Because `++n` yields the same value as produced by it's side-effect.

Answer (score 2):

The decrement will happen before the call to `func`, however `func` will be passed a copy of the old value still.

Consider the following modification to your program which illustrates this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int n;

void func(int m)
{
  printf("%d,%d\n", n, m);
}

int main()
{
  n = 10;
  func(n--);
  return 0;
}
```

Prints:

> 9,10

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is better expressed by this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int global_n;

void func(int n)
{
    printf("n = %d, global_n = %d\n",
            n, global_n);
}

int main()
{
   global_n = 10;
   func(global_n--);
   return 0;
}
```

This demonstrates that the function is passed the old value, but the decrement happens before the call.

```
n = 10, global_n = 9
```