# why it is acting like infinite loop

Tags: c

```
# include<stdio.h>

int somthing(int);
int main()
{
  int i=9;
  somthing(i);
  return 0;
}

int somthing(int i)
{
  if(i == 0)
    return 0;
  else
    printf("%d,", i);
  somthing (i--);
}
```

I am not getting why compiler prints only **9 9 9** and then says time out that is its running infinitely.
I did post decrement on **i variable** one less value should go into loop every time and it should print values from 9 to 0 , code works fine when doing pre decrement on **i variable** .

Comment: check what postfix `--` does!

Comment: [Postfix decrement](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7632276)

Comment: post fix doesnt decrement value right away instead when it is used again

Comment: is it not working because everytime function is called it creates new temporary variable for incoming integer value ? which always stays 9 as it doesnt decrement it right away ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int somthing(int i)
{
  if(i == 0)
    return 0;
  else
    printf("%d,", i);
    somthing (--i);
}
```

Do this instead. See if this works

Comment: it works, read what i wrote in above comments and see if i got right explanation for why it is not working

Answer (score 3):

**I did post decrement on i variable one less value should go into loop every time and it should print values from 9 to 0**

what you are using `i--` is post increment. It would send the value of i to the `something()` function and then decrement the value of `i`. so, the `somthing()` function always gets the value `9`. thus it goes to an infinite recursive call.

what you need is preincrement `--i`. It will decrement the value of `i` and then send it to the function `somthing()`